# How to get length of a character array in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to find the length of two different character array but I am only being allowed to use array.size only once.

How to bypass this problem?

```
fun chararraytostr(inp1: CharArray): String{
    var arlen: Int = inp1.size //here lies the problem
    var out1: String = ""
    for(j in 0..arlen-1){
        var str = inp1[j].toString()
        out1+=str
    }
    return out1
}

fun uppercase(input: String): String{
    var temp1: CharArray = input.toCharArray()
    var len = input.size //here lies the problem
    var temp3: Char
    for(i in 0..len-1){
        var temp2: Char = temp1[i]
        var ascii: Int = temp2.toInt()
        if(ascii<=122 && ascii>=97){
            ascii-=32
            temp3 = ascii.toChar()
            temp1[i] = temp3
        }else{}
    }
    var output = chararraytostr(temp1)
    return output
}

fun main(arg: Array<String>){
    var toupper = "Hi my friend!"
    println(uppercase(toupper))
}
```

It is always showing Unresolved reference: size. I don't know why. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `size` on the `String` variable instead of the `CharArray` variable. Use `temp1.size` instead of `input.size`.